# How can I select image through touch on tableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am new to app development. In my app when I click on my table view cell, the cell is selected and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method is triggered irrespective of whether I clicked on image or cell. I want the image to be selected when I click on the image, not the cell. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can add a custom button to your tableviewcell and give action to it

Comment: show ur tried code

Comment: Please be more specific when you are asking a question in SA. Show us some code what you have tried

Comment: I am navigating image from one view controller to another view controller. And I am using didSelectRowAtIndexPath method for this.

Answer (score 0):

Add  UITapGestureRecognizer  on your image view, and if you not want cell selection then off table view cell selection . on Tap function on image do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, add a custom `UIButton` and assign the image as background image of the button. Then add target to the button and handle your code inside the button target method

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];


        UIButton *imageButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:<Give the frame you want>];
        [imageButton setBackgroundImage:<your image> forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(imageButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell addSubview:imageButton];

    }

    return cell;
}
```

Here the best method is to create a custom `UITableViewCell` which have `imageButton` as an instance variable instead of creating it inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. Now in the `imageButtonClicked` method

```
-(void)imageButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {

    UIImage *image = sender.currentBackgroundImage;

    //Do the logic what you want here

}
```

Please give the frame of the button so that it is placed at the position you want.

I haven't tried out this code. If `sender.currentBackgroundImage` is not giving you the image, then create a custom button extending from UIButton. The custom button should have a UIImage variable as an instance variable. Assign the variable to the image you want when it is initialized(in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method). And then you can access the image in the button target method

Comment: I will be good if `UIButton *imageButton = [[UIButton alloc]  .......... forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell addSubview:imageButton];`  moved to custom UITableViewCell class. Every time calling `addSubview:` is costly.

Comment: Yea I'm agreeing with you. I did it this way just to show him how it's done. The best method is to create a custom UITableViewCell class

Comment: How to do it with UITableViewCell Class.Suggest me.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma Create a class extending from UITableViewCell and add this imageButton as an instance variable to it. Initialize the button, assign background image and add it as subview to the custom cell within the class itself. Then use the instance of that custom cell class in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.